# Prove that in a complete binary tree with $L$ levels, the total number of nodes $N \leq 2^{(L+1)} - 1$

Tags: proof-techniques, binary-trees

Anyone please answer the question:
Prove that in a complete binary tree with $L$ levels, the total number of nodes $N \leq 2^{(L+1)} - 1$.

Answer (score 1):

You should really show what you tried before asking, this is not a site for answering homework questions. Still, some hints.

You can use the principle of mathematical induction. Start with your base case, when $L = 0$ (i.e., there are no nodes so $N = 0$). Then

$$2^{0 + 1} - 1 = 2^1 - 1 = 1 \quad \text{and } 0 = N \leq 1 - 1 = 0.$$

Next, for your inductive hypothesis *assume* that a complete binary tree with $L = k$ levels satisfies $N \leq 2^{k + 1} - 1$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Next, consider a complete binary tree with $L = k + 1$ levels, the first $k$ levels form a complete binary tree themselves (Why?), so our inductive hypothesis implies that they contain no more than $2^{k + 1} - 1$ nodes. Then, the last level (level $k + 1$) of the tree can have at most $2^k$ nodes. I leave it to you to show that $N \leq 2^{(k + 1) + 1} - 1$ thus showing this holds for all $L = k$.